# How to create JIRA issue with assignee as unassigned using REST API

Tags: java, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I need to create an `Issue` in `JIRA` using the `REST API` from my `Java` program.  While doing this I want to set the `Assignee` field to `Unassigned`.  Everything that I have found in documentation and other questions has said to leave the `Assignee` field blank, however that will use the `Default Assignee`.  I want to ensure that the `Assignee` field is left as `Unassigned`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Assignee` field to `null` and it will leave the `Assignee` field as `Unassigned`.